# How can I fetch records with avoiding nested nil record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using `acts_as_paranoid` for logical deletion. 
When a record is deleted. The record won't disappear. It just gets timestamp in 'deleted_at' column, which means deleted.

In my model,

> Community has_many :topics

I fetched all Topics like this

```
@topics = Topic.page(params[:page]).order("updated_at DESC")
```

However, it gets **routing error** when it's displaying Topic record whose parent's Community is already deleted.

How can I fetch all the Topics whose parent 'Community' existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a scope on Community similar to

```
class Community
  def self.not_deleted
    where deleted_at: nil
  end
end
```

Then you could do

```
@topics = Topic.joins(:community).merge(Community.not_deleted).
  page(params[:page]).order("updated_at DESC")
```

Otherwise you could do

```
@topics = Topic.joins(:community).where( community: { deleted_at: nil } ).
  page(params[:page]).order("updated_at DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried 1st one, it returns this error:( undefined method `not_deleted'

Comment: You would have to define the not_deleted method in the Community class first like I did in the example